# Not getting required audio codec in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using Colab to run the code.

```
import os, sys, re

video_file_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/1111/Mrs.Serial Killer 2020 1080p 10bit NF WEBRip Hindi DD+5.1 Atmos x265 HEVC ESub - MoviePirate - Telly.mkv" #@param {type:"string"}
os.environ['fileName'] = filename_raw
os.environ['fileExtension'] = file_extension_raw

!ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$inputFile" -c copy -strict -2 "$outputPath"/"$fileName".mp4
```

**But the problem is after conversion of mkv video in mp4 format my html5 player can't play the audio. Video is running fine.**
Output :

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1
--toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared libavutil 55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100 libavcodec 57.107.100 / 57.107.100 libavformat 57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100 libavdevice 57. 10.100 / 57.
10.100 libavfilter 6.107.100 / 6.107.100 libavresample 3. 7. 0 / 3. 7. 0 libswscale 4. 8.100 / 4. 8.100 libswresample 2. 9.100 / 2. 9.100 libpostproc 54. 7.100 / 54. 7.100 Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/content/drive/Shared drives/Vedant/1111/Mrs.Serial Killer 2020 1080p 10bit NF WEBRip Hindi DD+5.1 Atmos x265 HEVC ESub - MoviePirate - Telly.mkv': Metadata: title : MoviePirate.in | Mrs.Serial Killer 2020 1080p 10bit NF WEBRip Hindi DD+5.1 Atmos x265 HEVC ESub - MoviePirate
- Telly.mkv encoder : libebml v1.3.10 + libmatroska v1.5.2 creation_time : 2020-05-01T15:55:34.000000Z Duration: 01:46:56.51, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2975 kb/s Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv), 1920x960, SAR 1:1 DAR 2:1, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 24 tbc (default) Metadata: title : MoviePirate.in BPS-eng : 2205883 DURATION-eng : 01:46:56.500000000 NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 153996 NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1769256160 _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v44.0.0 ('Domino') 64-bit _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-05-01 15:55:34 _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES Stream #0:1(hin): Audio: eac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 768 kb/s Metadata: title : MoviePirate.in BPS-eng : 768000 DURATION-eng : 01:46:56.512000000 NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 200516 NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 615985152 _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v44.0.0 ('Domino') 64-bit _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-05-01 15:55:34 _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip Metadata: title : MoviePirate.in BPS-eng : 42 DURATION-eng : 01:41:50.375000000 NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 1123 NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 32413
_STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v44.0.0 ('Domino') 64-bit _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-05-01 15:55:34 _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES File '/content/drive/Shared drives/Vedant/1111//Mrs.Serial Killer 2020 1080p 10bit NF WEBRip Hindi DD+5.1 Atmos x265 HEVC ESub - MoviePirate
- Telly.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y [mp4 @ 0x560897578c00] track 1: codec frame size is not set Output #0, mp4, to '/content/drive/Shared drives/Vedant/1111//Mrs.Serial Killer 2020 1080p 10bit NF WEBRip Hindi DD+5.1 Atmos x265 HEVC ESub - MoviePirate
- Telly.mp4': Metadata: title : MoviePirate.in | Mrs.Serial Killer 2020 1080p 10bit NF WEBRip Hindi DD+5.1 Atmos x265 HEVC ESub - MoviePirate - Telly.mkv encoder : Lavf57.83.100 Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(tv), 1920x960 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:1], q=2-31, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 16k tbn, 1k tbc (default) Metadata: title : MoviePirate.in BPS-eng : 2205883 DURATION-eng : 01:46:56.500000000 NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 153996 NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1769256160 _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v44.0.0 ('Domino') 64-bit _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-05-01 15:55:34
_STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES Stream #0:1(hin): Audio: eac3 (ec-3 / 0x332D6365), 48000 Hz,
5.1(side), fltp, 768 kb/s Metadata: title : MoviePirate.in BPS-eng : 768000 DURATION-eng : 01:46:56.512000000 NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 200516 NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 615985152 _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v44.0.0 ('Domino') 64-bit _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-05-01 15:55:34 _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES Stream mapping: Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy) Stream #0:1
-> #0:1 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help frame=153996 fps=10450 q=-1.0 Lsize= 2334010kB time=01:46:56.48 bitrate=2979.9kbits/s speed= 435x video:1727789kB audio:601548kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:2kB muxing overhead: 0.200594%    ffmpeg version
3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) configuration: --prefix=/usr
--extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared libavutil 55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100 libavcodec 57.107.100 / 57.107.100 libavformat 57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100 libavdevice 57. 10.100 / 57.
10.100 libavfilter 6.107.100 / 6.107.100 libavresample 3. 7. 0 / 3. 7. 0 libswscale 4. 8.100 / 4. 8.100 libswresample 2. 9.100 / 2. 9.100 libpostproc 54. 7.100 / 54. 7.100 Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/content/drive/Shared drives/Vedant/1111/Mrs.Serial Killer 2020 1080p 10bit NF WEBRip Hindi DD+5.1 Atmos x265 HEVC ESub - MoviePirate - Telly.mkv': Metadata: title : MoviePirate.in | Mrs.Serial Killer 2020 1080p 10bit NF WEBRip Hindi DD+5.1 Atmos x265 HEVC ESub - MoviePirate
- Telly.mkv encoder : libebml v1.3.10 + libmatroska v1.5.2 creation_time : 2020-05-01T15:55:34.000000Z Duration: 01:46:56.51, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2975 kb/s Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv), 1920x960, SAR 1:1 DAR 2:1, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 24 tbc (default) Metadata: title : MoviePirate.in BPS-eng : 2205883 DURATION-eng : 01:46:56.500000000 NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 153996 NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1769256160 _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v44.0.0 ('Domino') 64-bit _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-05-01 15:55:34 _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES Stream #0:1(hin): Audio: eac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 768 kb/s Metadata: title : MoviePirate.in BPS-eng : 768000 DURATION-eng : 01:46:56.512000000 NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 200516 NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 615985152 _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v44.0.0 ('Domino') 64-bit _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-05-01 15:55:34 _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip Metadata: title : MoviePirate.in BPS-eng : 42 DURATION-eng : 01:41:50.375000000 NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 1123 NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 32413
_STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v44.0.0 ('Domino') 64-bit _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-05-01 15:55:34 _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES File '/content/drive/Shared drives/Vedant/1111//Mrs.Serial Killer 2020 1080p 10bit NF WEBRip Hindi DD+5.1 Atmos x265 HEVC ESub - MoviePirate
- Telly.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y [mp4 @ 0x560897578c00] track 1: codec frame size is not set Output #0, mp4, to '/content/drive/Shared drives/Vedant/1111//Mrs.Serial Killer 2020 1080p 10bit NF WEBRip Hindi DD+5.1 Atmos x265 HEVC ESub - MoviePirate
- Telly.mp4': Metadata: title : MoviePirate.in | Mrs.Serial Killer 2020 1080p 10bit NF WEBRip Hindi DD+5.1 Atmos x265 HEVC ESub - MoviePirate - Telly.mkv encoder : Lavf57.83.100 Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(tv), 1920x960 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:1], q=2-31, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 16k tbn, 1k tbc (default) Metadata: title : MoviePirate.in BPS-eng : 2205883 DURATION-eng : 01:46:56.500000000 NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 153996 NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1769256160 _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v44.0.0 ('Domino') 64-bit _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-05-01 15:55:34
_STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES Stream #0:1(hin): Audio: eac3 (ec-3 / 0x332D6365), 48000 Hz,
5.1(side), fltp, 768 kb/s Metadata: title : MoviePirate.in BPS-eng : 768000 DURATION-eng : 01:46:56.512000000 NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 200516 NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 615985152 _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v44.0.0 ('Domino') 64-bit _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-05-01 15:55:34 _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES Stream mapping: Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy) Stream #0:1
-> #0:1 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help frame=153996 fps=10450 q=-1.0 Lsize= 2334010kB time=01:46:56.48 bitrate=2979.9kbits/s speed= 435x video:1727789kB audio:601548kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:2kB muxing overhead: 0.200594%
```

What changes should I do in the Code?

Comment: Show the complete log from the ffmpeg command (without `-hide_banner`).

Comment: @llogan I have edited the question and added the output please kindly check it. Thanks

Comment: What happened to the line breaks? It's too hard to parse without them.

Comment: I tried but line break is not being copied from colab.

Comment: And by the way it seems it have just changed the container.

Comment: @llogan But can you suggest me the code which will utilize the Colab TPU and give me mp4 format faster.!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that HTML5 does not support eac3 ([ATSC A/52 E-AC-3) audio. Re-encode it as AAC.

```
!ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$inputFile" -c copy -c:a aac -movflags +faststart "$outputPath"/"$fileName".mp4
```